# How do you assign the Assembly Location of an Excel VSTO Installation?

Tags: c#, installation, vsto

I'm creating a Document-Level Workbook/Template written in C# and using a VSTO Installer to deploy the code.  After installing the project I have full functionality of the Spreadsheet however, when I save or copy the installed sheet to another path outside the installation folder I get the following error:

[image: Uh Oh!]

With the following full details:

```
Name: 
From: file:///C:/Users/Kronos/Desktop/ExcelTemplate1.vsto

************** Exception Text **************
System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException: Downloading file:///C:/Users/Kronos/Desktop/ExcelTemplate1.vsto did not succeed. ---> System.Net.WebException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Kronos\Desktop\ExcelTemplate1.vsto'. ---> System.Net.WebException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Kronos\Desktop\ExcelTemplate1.vsto'. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Kronos\Desktop\ExcelTemplate1.vsto'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)
   at System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
   at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
   at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.GetManifests(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
```

I realize that this is due the to `.VSTO`, `.manifest` & `.DLL` files not being properly referenced as the Excel spreadsheet no longer resides in the installed path.  After doing [some research](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116/conversation/kronos-koders-kodes-of-horror) I can manually fix this by changing the copied/saved Excels `custom.xml` file within the `.xlsx` file from this:

```
name="_AssemblyLocation"><vt:lpwstr>ExcelTemplate1.vsto|ca022788-e7c0-41d8-b8ae-2c0ba9edbbf8|vstolocal
```

To this:

```
name="_AssemblyLocation"><vt:lpwstr>file://c:/<path to install dir>/ExcelTemplate1.vsto|ca022788-e7c0-41d8-b8ae-2c0ba9edbbf8|vstolocal
```

As this isn't a viable solution for my customers, how do I make the above changes using either C# code, or (more preferably) the installer?

*Note: I've tried creating a Custom Install Action ([per this MSDN Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx)) where the following is set for `CustomActionData`:*

```
/assemblyLocation="[TARGETDIR]ExcelWorkbookProject.dll"/deploymentManifestLocation="[TARGETDIR]ExcelWorkbookProject.vsto"/documentLocation="[TARGETDIR]ExcelWorkbookProject.xlsx"
```

*to no avail.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to follow the instructions outlined in the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx) you referenced, just a little more.  However this is a little bit confusing and there is an error in the article.  Hopefully this will help clarify:

### You NEED to define a user script similar to what is provided by the article

Within the article there is a file that you can [download](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/VSTO2010MSI/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4539) that contains the project example.  From there you can reference your `Custom Actions` against the output of that cs project.  Create a new project that is a CS Class Library, copy the following user script specific to solving YOUR issue:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AddCustomizationCustomAction
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class AddCustomization : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
        //Note: you'll have to get the Guid from your specific project in order for it to work.  The MSDN article show you how.
        static readonly Guid SolutionID = new Guid("20cb4d1d-3d14-43c9-93a8-7ebf98f50da5");

        public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
        {
            string[] nonpublicCachedDataMembers = null;


            // Use the following for debugging during the install
            //string parameters = "Parameters in Context.Paramters:";
            //foreach (DictionaryEntry parameter in Context.Parameters)
            //{
            //    parameters = parameters + "\n" + parameter.Key + ":" + parameter.Value;
            //}

            //MessageBox.Show(parameters);

            //MessageBox.Show("total items in parameters: " + Context.Parameters.Count);
            //MessageBox.Show("Document Manifest Location:" + Context.Parameters["deploymentManifestLocation"]);

            Uri deploymentManifestLocation = null;
            if (Uri.TryCreate(
                Context.Parameters["deploymentManifestLocation"],
                UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute,
                out deploymentManifestLocation) == false)
            {
                throw new InstallException(
                    "The location of the deployment manifest " +
                    "is missing or invalid.");
            }
            string documentLocation =
                Context.Parameters["documentLocation"];
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(documentLocation))
            {
                throw new InstallException(
                    "The location of the document is missing.");
            }
            string assemblyLocation =
                Context.Parameters["assemblyLocation"];
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(assemblyLocation))
            {
                throw new InstallException(
                    "The location of the assembly is missing.");
            }

            // use the following for debugging
            MessageBox.Show(documentLocation);

            if (ServerDocument.IsCustomized(documentLocation))
            {
                ServerDocument.RemoveCustomization(documentLocation);
            }
            ServerDocument.AddCustomization(
                documentLocation,
                assemblyLocation,
                SolutionID,
                deploymentManifestLocation,
                false,
                out nonpublicCachedDataMembers);
            stateSaver.Add("documentlocation", documentLocation);
            base.Install(stateSaver);
        }

        public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Commit(savedState);
        }

        public override void Rollback(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Rollback(savedState);
        }

        public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Uninstall(savedState);
        }

    }
}
```

This overrides the install procedure of the installer.  The `base.Install(stateSaver)` calls the rest of the code to continue the installation as normal.

### The Error in the MSDN Article:

The article says to use the following for the `CustomActionData` of the Install Custom Action:

```
/assemblyLocation="[TARGETDIR]<YourProjectName>.dll"/deploymentManifestLocation="[TARGETDIR]<YourProjectName>.vsto"/documentLocation="[TARGETDIR]<YourProjectName>.xltx"
```

However it should be this (note the spaces between params):

```
/assemblyLocation="[TARGETDIR]<YourProjectName>.dll" /deploymentManifestLocation="[TARGETDIR]<YourProjectName>.vsto" /documentLocation="[TARGETDIR]<YourProejctName>.xltx"
```

This should solve your issues, however make sure to rebuild any changes to your Excel Project to the release build before rebuilding your installer as it's pointed to the release and not the debug.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the information here - especially the information regarding the error in the MSDN article.  I was about ready to put my foot through the screen over this.

(Microsoft doesn't proof-read and check their material for accuracy??)

Comment: @StevenC.Britton your welcome, however might I suggest that if you can use an install shield installation instead.  It's a bit easier to use and setup.

Answer (score 1):

While James Mertz answer is spot on, it's also a bit dated (although it just saved me after a day of pulling my hair out). For newer versions of Visual Studios the instructions for this part of the application build have moved to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2017). I suggest that you go read them, or you can read my cliff notes version below:

The new console application that should be built as a new project in your existing solution. The `Program.cs` should look like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications;

namespace SetExcelDocumentProperties
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string assemblyLocation = "";
            Guid solutionID = new Guid();
            Uri deploymentManifestLocation = null;
            string documentLocation = "";
            string[] nonpublicCachedDataMembers = null;

            for (int i = 0; i <= args.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(args[i]);
                string[] oArugment = args[i].Split('=');

                switch (oArugment[0])
                {
                    case "/assemblyLocation":
                        assemblyLocation = oArugment[1];
                        break;
                    case "/deploymentManifestLocation":
                        if (!Uri.TryCreate(oArugment[1], UriKind.Absolute, out deploymentManifestLocation))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error creating URI");
                        }
                        break;
                    case "/documentLocation":
                        documentLocation = oArugment[1];
                        break;
                    case "/solutionID":
                        solutionID = Guid.Parse(oArugment[1]);
                        break;
                }
            }
            try
            {
                ServerDocument.RemoveCustomization(documentLocation);
                ServerDocument.AddCustomization(documentLocation, assemblyLocation,
                                            solutionID, deploymentManifestLocation,
                                            true, out nonpublicCachedDataMembers);

            }
            catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The specified document does not exist.");
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The specified document is read-only.");
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The customization could not be removed.\n" +
                    ex.Message);
            }
            catch (DocumentNotCustomizedException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The document could not be customized.\n" +
                    ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There's no need to change any of that as we will be passing parameters to it from the InstallShield Setup.

This requires two references in the new project:

- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument

Now to call this new application after installation is complete and pass it parameters (***also in that instruction link***): add the Primary Output from that new project to your Install Shield "Application Files"

Then go to *"Custom Action"* in Install Shield and double click on *"After Setup Complete Success Dialog"* in the *"Custom Actions During Installation"* section. This is where you can run vbscript, jscript, or an executable once installation is complete. Here we will run our new console application executable passing it parameters.

In your new *custom action*, in the list for the *Source Location* property, choose *"Installed with the Product"* and browse to your new projects *primary output* file where ever your VSTO application is to be installed on the destination.

Now in the *"Command Line"* property box you put the list of arguments that your console application requires to run:

```
/assemblyLocation="[INSTALLDIR]ExcelWorkbook.dll" /deploymentManifestLocation="[INSTALLDIR]ExcelWorkbook.vsto" /documentLocation="[INSTALLDIR]ExcelWorkbook.xlsx" /solutionID="Your Solution ID"
```

**Those have to be changed for your dll, vsto, workbook, and solution id**. The solution ID can be found inside of your `.csproj` file (out in a file explorer go find it and pop it open in notepad).

Now you're golden. When your application installs successfully this console application is launched and it will change the `manifestLocation` of your workbook to the install path instead of the relative path of the current workbook.

If the folks installing don't have admin privileges on their computer and you are installing into Program Files directory you may find that before performing this step they were able to install and run, but afterwards they can't. That's because the workbook is read-only in that location. You'll have to pick another location to install your application in that event (AppDataLocal is a good choice).