# Creating Excel Document-level customization with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: excel, visual-studio, vsto, clickonce

I created an Excel Document-level Customization by using Visual Studio 2015 Community which works fine on my laptop but I have troubles distributing the customization to others, for which I make use of ClickOnce. I'm new to Visual Basic and ClickOnce and my programming skills are limited to VBA. So any solution to solve my distribution problems is greatly appreciated.

I followed the steps of this microsoft tutorial (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc837158.aspx) in order to distribute the customization to others. I uploaded the files on my company's SharePoint environment and set this URL as the place for the VSTO Deployment manifest to look for updates. The files I uploaded are the Excel-file, a VSTO deployment manifest, a setup and the Application Files folder. If I download these files from SharePoint and run the Excel-file, it works fine. However when a college downloads the files on another laptop and runs the Excel-file, we get the error that it is not possible to download the VSTO from the URL. We get a similar error when we run the setup. And when I run the Excel-file online from the SharePoint folder I get the error that the location is not contained in the list of trusted locations.

We would like to distribute this customization to clients, preferably by just sending them the required files per e-mail.

If I understand the answer in this link ([best content on how to deploy and share a VSTO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081040/best-content-on-how-to-deploy-and-share-a-vsto-solution)) correctly it should be possible to run the customization without being connected to the internet, by saving all the required files on your hard drive. Although, I think I followed these instructions correctly, I'm not able to get the customization working on another pc.

How can I resolve my distribution problems? Either by using ClickOnce or other (preferable free) software.