# Excel Document based VSTO deployment

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

So here is the thing I would like to do:

Deploy the assemblies in a network location and specify in the .xlsx document properties, that the manifest and the assemblies are all at that network location (when the excel file is passed around, nothing needs to be passed along with it).

I have been searching the answer for this for a while. Not much information or MSDN documentation about this.  And the closest I get is this:

[best content on how to deploy and share a VSTO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081040/best-content-on-how-to-deploy-and-share-a-vsto-solution)

However, the answer provided was for Excel2010 and previous versions. Those properties settings are not found on Excel2013 onwards.

Could somebody please help?

Comment: Are you referring to _AssemblyLocation? It's still there in Word 2013. I would be surprised if it was missing in Excel.

Comment: Where can I find it? Thank you.

Comment: File, Info, Properties, Advanced Properties, Custom

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_AssemblyLocation is still present, in the same place it was in 2010, under File, Info, Properties, Advanced Properties, Custom.